# Duda sobre TypeError: string indices must be integers Python InstaBot

Tags: python

Hola comunidad de StackOverflow en español, estoy trabajando en este pequeño script de Python usando instabot y pandas para listar la cantidad de seguidores de determinada cuenta de IG y guardarlos en un dataframe, sin embargo se me está complicando un poco ya que me da un error de principantes

```
from instabot import Bot
import pandas as pd

total_seguidores = []
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="usuario", password="contraseña")

followers = bot.get_user_followers("cuenta_ig")
for follower in followers:
    total_seguidores.append({
        "pk": follower["pk"],
        "username": follower["username"],
        "full_name": follower["full_name"],
        "is_private": follower["is_private"],
        "profile_pic_url": follower["profile_pic_url"],
        "profile_pic_id": follower["profile_pic_id"],
        "is_verified": follower["is_verified"],
        "follow_friction_type": follower["follow_friction_type"]

    })
   

df = pd.DataFrame(total_seguidores)
print(df)
df.to_csv("total_seguidores_ig.csv")
```

**error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\codeecuadorstats\ig selenium.py", line 13, in <module>
    "pk": follower["pk"],
  TypeError: string indices must be integers
 2021-07-02 15:21:42,516 - INFO - Total requests: 35
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: `followers` es un diccionario una lista? o que?

Comment: `followers` es una lista, `total_seguidores` es mi diccionario vacío para hacer append, por cierto gracias por re editar mi pregunta @Christian

Comment: En el caso de que estés usando selenium; asegúrate de que los elementos obtenidos con selenium sean del mismo tipo de dato que estas esperando. Es decir, si estas esperando un `int` para el campo `PK`, asegúrate de pasar a enteros todos los pk que obtengas con selenium.

Comment: Hola, no he usado selenium para este pequeño script, en ese caso que tendría que hacer?

Comment: @AarónParodi no es necesario cambiar de herramienta para solucionar tu error, solo debes entender como funcionan las estructuras de datos (listas, diccionarios, tuplas, sets)